# Why an operator can have nonvanishing determinant while have no unique inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, greens-function

Let's take the operator $L=(\partial_x^2+m^2)\delta(x-y)$ as an example. It operates in the function space in the following way
$$\int dy\ (\partial_x^2+m^2)\delta(x-y)f(y)=(\partial_x^2+m^2)f(x).$$ 
The eigen equations are
$$\int dy\ (\partial_x^2+m^2)\delta(x-y)f(y)=(\partial_x^2+m^2)f(x)=k(\sigma)f(x,\sigma),$$
where $\sigma$ simply labels the eigenfunctions. For our example we have $k(\sigma)=-\sigma^2+m^2$ and $f(x,\sigma)=e^{i\sigma x}$. 
And for its inverse, we have
$$\int dy\ (\partial_x^2+m^2)\delta(x-y)G(y-z)=\delta(x-z),$$
namely
$$(\partial_x^2+m^2)G(x-z)=\delta(x-z).\tag{1}$$
$G(x-z)$ is simply the Green's function. All these stuff are completely analogy with the discrete case.
The trace is defined as
$$tr L=\int d\sigma k(\sigma)$$
and we can obtain the determinant by $\log \det L=tr \log L$.

Now comes my question, since from Eq.(1) we can not obtain an unique Green's function (recall the boundary conditions if we want to specify the solution). Then when a operator $L$ has no unique inverse, shouldn't it have vanishing determinant?

Comment: In infinite dimensions, injectivity and surjectivity no longer go hand-in-hand. The quintessential examples are in the sequence spaces $\ell^p$, where forward shift on $\ell^p$ is injective but not surjective while the backward shift is surjective but not injective. So if your "determinant" is an infinite dimensional analogue of "the signed volume of the image of the unit cube" (I don't entirely understand your definition of "determinant", actually), then it is possible for this to be positive (because of surjectivity) even though no inverse exists (because of failure of injectivity).

Comment: @Ian : what is the meaning of his $\int k(\sigma) d\sigma$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I'm actually not sure, it looks more like a trace than a determinant...

Comment: @user1952009, I am sorry, I modified my post.

Comment: @lan I have changed my post for the definition of determinant.

Comment: How do you know what measure to put on the spectrum? In finite dimensions there is an obvious measure: the measure is a sum of Dirac deltas at each eigenvalue, each multiplied by the algebraic multiplicity. For the discrete part of the spectrum this makes sense even in functional analysis. What do you do about the continuous spectrum?

Comment: @lan Thank you very much for your answer. Your answer seems to answer my question completely. But I am a student studying physics, so I need to make some concepts you mentioned here clear first.